# ReferenceError: message is not defined

Tags: discord

```
const Discord = require ('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'TOKEN';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
  console.log('Online');

  if(msg.includes('hi')) {
    message.delete();
    message.author.send('hello')
  }
})
bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code into a `.on()` function. For example, to listen for messages:

```js
const Discord = require ('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'TOKEN';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
  console.log('Online');
})

bot.on('message', (message) => {
  if(message.includes('hi')) {
    message.delete();
    message.author.send('hello')
  }
})

bot.login(token);
```

Note you can't use `msg` **and** `message`, you must choose one variable name.